# C# - How can I cast KeyValuePair<string,object> to KeyValuePair<object,object>?

Tags: c#, casting, key-value

In C#, how can I cast **KeyValuePair<string, object>** to **KeyValuePair<object, object>**? I tried the following but it does not work:

```
public static KeyValuePair<object, object> DoTheCast(KeyValuePair<string, object> the_obj)
{
    return (KeyValuePair<object, object>)the_obj;
}
```

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[System.String,System.Object]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[System.Object,System.Object]'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wont be able to *cast* perse, however you can just create a new one

```
public static KeyValuePair<object, object> DoTheCast(KeyValuePair<string, object> the_obj)    
     => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(the_obj.Key, the_obj.Value);
```